# Почему не отображается background: url(img/rect_yel.png) при наведении на <a class="recent"></a> (bootstrapv4)?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```css
.info {
    color: red;
    background-image: url(img/rect_yel.png);
}

.recent:hover ~ .info {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a class="recent" href=#>
                <img src="img/rect_yel.png" alt="J D">
                </a>
                <div class="info d-none">
                    <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
                </div>
                <H5>Jonh Doeeh</H5>
                <p>Lead Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

все работает

```css
.info {
    color: red;
    background-image: url(http://333v.ru/uploads/00/000a7db0d4c688263a3e8d09e1f5fa93.jpg);
}

.recent:hover ~ .info {
    display: block !important;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a class="recent" href=#>
                <img src="img/rect_yel.png" alt="J D">
                </a>
                <div class="info d-none">
                    <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
                </div>
                <H5>Jonh Doeeh</H5>
                <p>Lead Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```